# How to fix Freelancer not connecting to a localhost server?

Tags: freelancer

When running a Freelancer server and client on the same machine, the attempt of trying to connect results in a "takes longer than usual"-ish message that never vanishes. Firewall settings are fine and I also tried launching both server and client in compatibility modes to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things go horribly wrong when IPv6 is available. You have to disable it for *all* local network interfaces, including virtual ones like the ones from VMWare.